# How to wait for program to finish, and pipe stdin to stdout when it's done?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to figure out how to wait for a command to complete, and then pipe stdin to stdout. I'm on a mac, but I think my question is more about how to wait for a process to complete and pipe the output then anything to do with a mac.

I've noticed that on the mac, I can run a few `say` commands together, and they wait for each phrase to be fully spoken before starting the next one, if I use the `&&` operator to join them up.

```
$ say "stage 1" && say "stage 2"
```

Here's where the real use case is - I've got a bash script that I'd like to have it just pass stdin to stdout, *after* it finishes saying something.

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | say_and_pass "stage 1" | grep -v test | say_and_pass "stage 2"
```

So conceptually, this would say aloud, "stage 1", then immediately say "stage 2", and then dump the grepped contents of `/etc/password` to stdout.

My initial crack at the `say_and_pass` script is this:

### say_and_pass

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
OUT="$*"
say "$OUT" && cat
```

But it doesn't seem to work ;-)

EDIT: I changed the example above to use `say_and_pass "stage2"` as the final command, which is needed for [my solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437619/22734) to work...

Comment: Please tell us in what way this does not work.  If there's an error message, please include this in full. Your code works for me on an up-to-date macOS machine, but I don't know if it's working in the way that you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I'm using HIgh Sierra, and when I run the above command that uses `say_and_pass`, it says both "stage 1" and "stage 2" at the same time, instantly. I'd like it to say "stage 1", then immediately say "stage 2" afterwards.  The intent of this is for me to be able to put audio alerts in the middle of a series of pipes. That way I'll know when some stages have completed. This is of course for long running processes that I don't want to sit and have to watch to see if they're done. The thing is sometimes, the scripts will finish fast, and talk over top of each other.

Comment: In testing on my Mac here, `say` blocks until it is done outputting the audio; it should not overlap itself unless you are running two instances of `say` simultaneously.  That said, your I/O stream is broken in your example here, so with pipes you essentially _are_ running two instances of 'say' near-parallel.  Compare `echo "foo" 1>&2 | say "foo" | echo "bar" 1>&2 | say "bar"` to `echo "foo" 1>&2 ; say "foo" ; echo "bar" 1>&2 ; say "bar"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of `say_and_pass` does what OP asks for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create a temporary file to store stdin
TEMP_STDIN="$(mktemp)"

# Capture stdin and save it to temporary file
cat - > "${TEMP_STDIN}"

# say message, but prevent any output to stdout
say "$@" > /dev/null

# Dump saved stdin to stdout
cat "${TEMP_STDIN}"

# Clean up, but prevent any output to stdout
rm -f "${TEMP_STDIN}" > /dev/null
```

It uses a temporary file, like @DopeGhoti suggests, but keeps any of the other logic (the `grep`, for instance) out of the script. This makes it so that `say_and_pass` is more general and reusable.

My interpretation of the goal/purpose is that we want an audible way to monitor progress of a potentially long pipeline.

So when running:

```
cmd1 | say_and_pass "stage 1" | cmd2 | say_and_pass "stage 2"
```

As a user, you can audibly know that `cmd1` has fully completed its execution; the trade-off is that `cmd2` cannot begin processing its stdin until `cmd1` is complete. But it seems that the OP is aware of this trade-off and willing to make it.

This is similar to the answer by @BradParks, but is not limited by the memory available to bash (as @agc points out), and is slightly more careful about avoiding accidental pollution of stdout.

Also note that there's no need to capture the message into a variable of its own, so we also simply forward `"$@"` to `say`.

Comment: There's already an accepted answer that resolves the issue. Also DopeGhoti's answer resolves it. Have you tested your solution so you can confirm it works? If yes, could you please expand the answer to explain what exactly does this add to DopeGhoti's answer? If you haven't tested and can't confirm I'd suggest removing the answer.

Comment: If another answer is missing bits, you should suggest a modification to that answer. Each answer needs to be self-contained.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/389788)

Comment: I'm the OP, and have tested this solution on my mac, and it does exactly what I want, and is a better version of my answer! Thanks @walter

Answer (score 1):

> Here's where the real use case is - I've got a bash script that I'd like to have it just pass stdin to stdout, after it finishes saying something.
>
> ```
> $ cat /etc/password | say_and_pass "stage 1" | grep -v test | say "stage 2"
> ```

The problem with what you're trying to do here is that you seem to have two data streams- one for `say` and one for text processing (i. e. `cat` and `grep`).

You can't use a single pipeline for this, as it will just commingle the data.  `cat /etc/passwd | say` will have your computer attempt to speak the entire contents of the file.  Furthermore, `say` does not write *anything* to standard output, so nothing would go any farther down the pipeline.

If you do want to "interrupt" your data processing stream to handle separate output to other utilities like `say`, you need to either set yourself up with a FIFO (i. e. a "named pipe") for one or the other of your data streams, or use temporary files written to disk.

Your demonstrative use-case isn't very helpful for an example, as notwithstanding the `say`s, you're just `grep`ping a file, which can be done in one step with `grep -v test /etc/passwd` (`cat file | grep pattern` is a [useless use of `cat`](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cat_(Unix)#/UUOC_(Useless_Use_Of_Cat))).

All that said, an example using a scratch file:

```
scratch=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $scratch" EXIT
cat /etc/passwd > $scratch
say "Stage one"
grep -v test $scratch
say "Stage two"
```

And one used a named pipe for `say`:

```
mkfifo youtalktoomuch
say youtalktoomuch &
exec 3> youtalktoomuch
do_thing_one
echo "Stage one" > youtalktoomuch
do_thing_two
echo "Stage two" > youtalktoomuch
exec 3>&-
rm youtalktoomuch

Once again, though, if you need to connect the output of `do_thing_one` to the input of `do_thing_two` without piping one into the other, you will need to use either another named pipe or a scratch file on disk to hold the data.
```

Comment: He's not trying to get `say` to say the contents of the file, as far as I can tell, just "stage 1" and "stage 2".

Comment: I know, but as presented `cat file | say` _will_ say the contents of the file.  That's the problem.

Comment: Even when `say` is given a command line argument?

Comment: In that case, the argument is ignored, making the useless use of `cat` even more useless (:

Comment: @Kusalananda - correct - it should only speak "stage 1" and "stage 2" in my example, not the input to the script

Comment: @DopeGhoti I can't reproduce what you said above.  `echo hello | say "goodbye"` says "goodbye".

Comment: The only issue here is a timing issue. As all parts of the pipeline are started simultaneously, the `say` has to come after the `cat`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti - Thanks for the feedback - I'm not running `cat /etc/password | say`, I'm piping it to my own script `say_and_pass`, which does use say internally, but isn't intending to pass stdin to `say`. The `say` in the script will use the command line args that were passed in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was consume all of stdin at the start of my script... I don't want it to process stdin as it's received, but when the entire previous command in the pipe chain completes.

So my `say_and_pass` script is simply this, which works for my use case!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OUT=$(cat -)

MSG="$*"
say "$MSG"

echo "$OUT"
```

Comment: It may work for the use case, but it's not general.  For example it won't work for files larger than `bash`'s available memory.

Comment: @agc - now that I've given it more thought, there's no way it can work any other way... normally piping passes content through the entire pipe line every time a line of input is received.... which is why my previous attempts didnt work. Any other approach doesnt make sense...

Comment: Consider using a temporary file instead of a variable, like DopeGhoti. Also, you might want to protect against unexpected stdout coming from the "say" command:

    `say "$MSG" > /dev/null`

Comment: @Walter - can you add that as another answer, and I'll use it then as the accepted, best answer

Comment: Thanks @BradParks! I undeleted and updated my answer.

Comment: nice.... thanks, and... done!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
say "stage 1" && cat /etc/passwd  |  { say "stage 2" && grep -v test ; }
```

I don't actually have `say` on my system, but this works:

```
espeak "stage 1" && cat /etc/passwd  |  { espeak "stage 2" && grep -v test ; }
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, since `cat` doesn't start until *after* the word "one" is spoken.

Answer (score 0):

H!

I'd suggest, based on your own answer, to just dump stdin to stdout, removing the part which stores it to a variable. This should reduce memory consumption, and make the pipe chain work as pipes should (one line in, it gets processed, and the result sent to the next process).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MSG="$*"
say "$MSG"

cat -
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it and it seems that both "says" happen at the same time using this.... I think doing it in a subshell forces the full stdin to be consumed.... try out the example I have... does it work for you? ie `$ cat /etc/passwd | say_and_pass "stage 1" | grep -v test | say_and_pass "stage 2"`

Answer (score -3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
OUT="$*"
say "$OUT" | cat -
```

If you use &&, its meaning , do fisrt command after do second command but fisrt command result not important for second command. I mean you have 2 different command, because you use &&. If you use |, its means fisrt command do something and give something for second command. The end, you should give a attribute for cat command.
Sorry my english by the way

Comment: There is no output from `say` to pipe.